# Align inside div to right bottom in CSS

Tags: css

what is the easiest way to put my inside div to bottom right corner?

```
<div style="width:200px; height:200px; border:3px #FF6666 solid">
<div style="font-weight:bold; text-align:right;">Krishna</div>
</div>
```

This is my code.. Thank you all

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this, setting your outer `div` to `position: relative;` ensure that the inner `div` will stay inside it when set to `position: absolute;`. Then you can specify it to sit in the bottom right corner by setting `bottom: 0; right: 0;`.

```
<div style="width:200px; height:200px; border:3px #FF6666 solid; position: relative">
  <div style="font-weight:bold; text-align:right;position: absolute;bottom: 0; right: 0; ">Krishna</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the parent of the div you can just position it absolute:

```
<div style="width:200px; height:200px; border:3px #FF6666 solid;position: relative;">
    <div style="font-weight:bold; text-align:right;position: absolute; bottom:0; right:0">Krishna</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="width:200px; height:200px; border:3px #FF6666 solid; position: relative">
  <div style="font-weight:bold; position: absolute;bottom: 0; right: 0; ">Krishna</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified your fiddle with inner div. Also added watermark to it.
See the updated code here : http://jsfiddle.net/8Lu1vpbr/

```css
#outerDiv
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 180px;
    border:3px #F02020 solid;
    position:relative;
}

#bottomRight
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;    
}

.watermark 
{
    opacity: 0.5;
    color: BLACK;
    padding-right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outerDiv">
<span> This is some content. <br />The bottom aligned item can be watermarked if needed.</span>
<div class='watermark' id="bottomRight">I am here!!!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/9MYFM/

You have to change the `position` to `absolute`.